# C# reuse GZipStream for more than one decompressions

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I need to compress and decompress millions of strings individually.  The first loop works.  The second doesn't.  Basically I don't know how to use streams.  How do I get the second method, the one that reuses streams, to work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string s = "Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah ";
            for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {
                var aCompressed = Zip(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
                var aDecompressed = UnZip(aCompressed, 0, aCompressed.Length);
                string sDbg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aDecompressed);
                Debug.Assert(sDbg == s);
            }
            // This loop is an utter failure.
            var UnZipper = new CUnZip(); // attempt to setup all the unzip framework once
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
                var aCompressed = Zip(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
                var aDecompressed = UnZipper.UnZip(aCompressed, 0, aCompressed.Length);
                string sDbg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aDecompressed);
                Debug.Assert(sDbg == s);
            }
        }
        static byte[] Zip(byte[] aIn) {
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (var tinyStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                using (var mStream = new MemoryStream(aIn))
                    mStream.CopyTo(tinyStream);
                return outStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        static byte[] UnZip(byte[] aIn, int i0, int cb) {
            using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(aIn, i0, cb))
            using (var bigStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var bigStreamOut = new MemoryStream()) {
                bigStream.CopyTo(bigStreamOut);
                return bigStreamOut.ToArray();
            }
        }
        // this class is an utter failure
        class CUnZip {
            GZipStream bigStream;
            MemoryStream inStream, bigStreamOut;
            BinaryWriter argh;
            public CUnZip() {
                inStream = new MemoryStream();
                argh = new BinaryWriter(inStream);
                bigStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                bigStreamOut = new MemoryStream();
            }
            public byte[] UnZip(byte[] aIn, int i0, int cb) {
                argh.Write(aIn, i0, cb);
                argh.Flush();
                bigStream.CopyTo(bigStreamOut);
                return bigStreamOut.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define doesn't work. Wrong results? Errors? Something else? But simply said: you can't just shove more data into the decompression and assume it'll happily comply and do what you want. You have to create new ones with fresh state.

Comment: Please point to specific details, instead of assuming we will be able to guess, first and second loops and point of failures as perceived by you

Comment: `bigStream = new GZipStream(inStream, ...` Why are you using `inStream` there. For fun?

Comment: @Orkhan.  This is the first time i have used streams.  I did it because I don't know better.

Comment: @Mrinal.  Second loop always produces an empty string.

Comment: @Sami.  Second loop always produces an empty string

Comment: @Orkhan.  How do you do it without instream?

Comment: @johnnycrash: Hmm, I missed that you are writing into `instream` using `BinaryWriter`

Comment: @orkhan any ideas how to do it any differently?  Can i use the BinaryWriter to write into the GZipStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your code following will resolve the issue:

```
inStream.Position = 0;
```

Set it post `argh.Flush()` in the `class CUnZip` - `UnZip Method`

**Details:**

As you are reusing the `MemoryStream` in the `CUnZip` class, its position is set to the last byte written and to do any operation, that needs it to be read, you need to reset the `position` to the beginning (0), else it has nothing to read, therefore even when `stream` contained the data it cannot be read, as it was pointing to the end of `stream`

Comment: The gzip stream might have some internal state that cannot be reset.

Comment: Reusing everything made unzipping a LOT faster.